# How to solve below Scenario, using SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having lot of data like this,here I've given sample data only,So Case when clause not suitable for this,

```
  DECLARE @T TABLE (EID INT, VALUE VARCHAR(50),CATEGORY VARCHAR(50),CATEGORY1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1,'JHON','NAME',NULL
UNION
SELECT 2,'MARY','NAME',NULL
UNION
SELECT 1,'IT','DEPT',NULL
UNION
SELECT 1,'85204-00065',NULL,'PHONE'
UNION
SELECT 1,'MALE',NULL,'GENDER'
UNION
SELECT 2,'85285-00525',NULL,'PHONE'
UNION
SELECT 2,'FEMALE',NULL,'GENDER'
UNION
SELECT 2,'BPO','DEPT',NULL

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Expected Output:

```
EId  Name   Dept    Gender  Phone
1    Jhon   IT      Male    85204-00065
2    Mary   Bpo     Female  85285-00525
```

Any one Provide better solution for this scenario.

Comment: I can't see any relation between rows ...

Comment: Looks like some variant of [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). Generally frowned upon outside specialist scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pivot, coalesce and dynamic query as below:

```
declare @cols1 varchar(max)
declare @cols2 varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select Distinct ','+QuoteName(Coalesce(Category,Category1)) from YourEmpData for xml path('')),1,1,'')
Select @Cols2 = 'Coalesce(' +stuff((Select ','+ QUOTENAME(Column_Name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'YourEmpData' and COLUMN_NAME not in ('EID', 'VALUE') for xml path('')),1,1,'') + ')'

Select @query = '   Select * from (
        Select EID, [Value], ' + @cols2 + ' as Categories FROM YourEmpData ) a
        pivot (max([Value]) for [Categories] in (' + @cols1 + ')) p '

select @query --uncomment and execute if your query generated correct
--exec sp_executesql @query
```